# Giving access to only User with USER_ROLE Permission

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am getting the following error

```
Class
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException
Message
EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'ADMIN_ROLE' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot'
```

I am trying to access the view My.GSP and i am login as a `USER_ROLE`

--

```
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

class MyController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

    @Secured(['ADMIN_ROLE','USER_ROLE'])
    def index() {
        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    }
    @Secured(['USER_ROLE'])
    def list(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        [patientInstanceList: Patient.list(params), patientInstanceTotal: Patient.count()]
    }
    @Secured(['USER_ROLE'])
    def create() {
        [patientInstance: new Patient(params)]
    }
    @Secured(['USER_ROLE'])
    def save() {
        def patientInstance = new Patient(params)
        if (!patientInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [patientInstance: patientInstance])
            return
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'patient.label', default: 'Patient'), patientInstance.id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: patientInstance.id)
    }
```

DB

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you 100% sure the ADMIN_ROLE has been properly created?

Comment: I have edited my post. I included a screenshot of my DB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the default settings of the spring security plugin in Grails role names *must* start with the prefix `"ROLE_"`, so rename your `ADMIN_ROLE` to `ROLE_ADMIN` and `USER_ROLE` to `ROLE_USER`.

[This forum post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/other-spring-related/grails/89083-spring-security-plug-in-role-prefix-mandatory) explains why it works like that by default, and how you can configure it differently if required.